# Exception:the component does not have a resource identified by the uri in Window Xp

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have released the application On VS2010, and it run well on Window7 or 10, but when it run on Window XP, the application throw this exception.
Ps:the dll whicn got problem is the assemblie loaded from local dynamic.

Here is part of code of the component that threw the exception when InitializeComponent.

VsaTab is a usercontrol defined at other assembly.

```
<tech:VsaTab x:Class="WT.Meter.Framework.Technologies.SampleVsaTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:tech="clr-namespace:WT.Meter.Framework.Technology;assembly=WT.Meter.Framework.Technology"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WT.Meter.Framework.Technologies"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WT.Meter.Controls;assembly=WT.Meter.Controls"
         xmlns:localResource="clr-namespace:WT.Meter.Common.LocalResource;assembly=WT.Meter.Common.LocalResource"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300">
```

Comment: Could you please show us more details of your coding?

Comment: thanks, i have add some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both systems run the same version of the .NET framework.

Comment: the same .net 4

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind for your `tech:VsaTab UserControl`, wrap the InitializeComponent() method in a `try..catch`, when the exception is thrown it will most likely show you more detail on which file it is failing to load.

I've had this issue where the styles were not loading correctly for the application - and was referencing a DLL with the wrong public key.

So in your code behind:

```
constructor() {
   try {
       InitializeComponent();
   catch (Exception ex) {
       // Place a debugger here to see the InnerExcepion
   }
}
```

You will most likely see that it it is trying to reference some Microsoft library that is not found on the machine - make sure you have the samve versions of DotNetFramework installed on the WindowsXP machine